# Toggling components depending of the current path in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, layout, routes, nuxt.js, vue-router

My `layouts/default.vue` looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-app style="background-color: transparent; color: unset">
    <v-main>
      <ActHeader></ActHeader>
      <Nuxt
        v-if="
          !$nuxt.isOffline ||
          $route.name == 'profile-downloads' ||
          $route.name == 'profile-downloads-id'
        "
        style="min-height: 300px"
      />
      <Footer />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Footer,
  },
  async fetch() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('store/retrieveSettings')
    await this.$store.dispatch('store/retrieveMenus')
  },
}
</script>
```

I don't want to show `actHeader` and `Footer` components into the first page(`/`) but in other pages(`/about`) I want to show these components.

---

I'm already aware of finding out URL and using watch like this:

```js
watch: {
  $route (to, from) {
    //false actHeader and Footer Components!
  }
}
```

and it's actually working but I'm looking for a better answer, maybe something more logical.

Comment: What is the `watch` doing here?

Comment: for example get path with (window.location.pathname) and if its not '/someUrl' then do the false in Footer Component, and then when the client wants to go to another route we can check it with this watch, by the way thanks for ur answer , i  guess there is no any better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special magic, use a conditional on each component, no cleaner way of doing otherwise (no need to over-engineer here).

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <act-header v-if="$route.name !== 'index'"></act-header>
    <nuxt />
    <footer-comp v-if="$route.name !== 'index'"></footer-comp>
  </div>
</template>
```